# Find JarBundler and use it on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, jar, jarbundler

I've installed XCode onto my computer to use the Jar Bundler. However, I can't find the executable for this!

I searched for Jar Bundler in spotlight and JarBundler.java comes up from Xcode. How do I use it to compile my program as a Mac app?

Comment: I don't think Apple supports it any more - [This](https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler/) is the closest alternative I've found to Sun's previous effort. [There are others](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+app+bundler&oq=java+app+bundler&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3629j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=java+appbundler) if you're interested in doing some research

Comment: @MadProgrammer how do I get the jar file from it? It doesn't have to be a runnable jar file, I just need it in jar form.

Comment: Build it ......